# Can't build libxml++

Tags: libxml2

I have some legacy code which uses libxml++. I try to build it on RedHat:
./configure
make.

There is a compilation error in libxml++/parsers/parser.cc:
parser.cc:192: error: 'auto_ptr' is not a member of 'std'

If I include  in this file, there are much more other errors.
Maybe I should pass some extra options for configure?

Anybody have a ready rpm with libxml++-2.6 for RedHat?

Answer (score 0):

I included header memory in 2 files: libxml++/parsers/parser.cc, libxml++/parsers/textreader.h

After that I compiled the library.